# web scraping of a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I want to scrape data from the table on [this page](http://datacenter.mep.gov.cn/index!getWaterplace.action?WATERPLACE=%E5%90%89%E6%9E%97%E6%BA%AA%E6%B5%AA%E5%8F%A3&YEAR=2016&WISSUE=1)

But both `GET` from `httr` or `read_html` from `rvest` cannot read the table. I've check the structure of this webpage and cannot find any POST or GET request about fetching data when loading the webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the page source we can see that the table is embedded in a frame. The URL for the table itself is [at this link](http://datacenter.mep.gov.cn:8099/ths-report/report!list.action?xmlname=1466632112484&V_YEAR=2016&V_waterplace=%27%E5%90%89%E6%9E%97%E6%BA%AA%E6%B5%AA%E5%8F%A3%27).

So you can try:

```
u <- "http://datacenter.mep.gov.cn:8099/ths-report/report!list.action?xmlname=1466632112484&V_YEAR=2016&V_waterplace=%27%E5%90%89%E6%9E%97%E6%BA%AA%E6%B5%AA%E5%8F%A3%27"

mytable <- u %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node("table") %>%
  html_table()
```

then some cleaning up to deal with the non-English characters.